# Can Angular ngStyle take more than one function? What's the workaround if not?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-style

## With ngStyle, are you able to add multiple conditions to multiple attributes?

I need to change my text color and background color based on a certain JSON value.

### Background Info:

I am working to make a tab bar similar to a browser. In each tab there is a *header/title* and *subheader*. The **Subheader's** style changes based on the tab/array data. Here is what the tab-bar design looks like:
[image]

I'm focusing on the Subheader style, the Planning and FPE ones.

Here is what my tab array looks like:

```
 tabs = [
    {
      flightName: "Flight 1",
      stagePhase: "PRE-FPE",
      control: "View Only"
    },
    {
      flightName: "Flight 2",
      stagePhase: "PLANNING",
      control: "Plan and Load"
    },
    {
      flightName: "Flight 3",
      stagePhase: "PLANNING",
      control: "Closeout"
    },
    {
      flightName: "Flight 4",
      stagePhase: "FPE",
      control: "View Only"
    }
  ];
```

If the `tabs.tab.control` attribute is `"View Only"` then the `background-color` will be transparent,
`"Plan and Load"` : light grey,
and `"Closeout"` : white and then ***also change the text-color*** to ***dark***.

So for the background color alone ngStyle function can look like: (Typescript)

```
getBgColor(control) {
  switch (control) {
    case 'View Only':
      return '#ffcccc00';
    case 'Editing':
      return '#cce6ff44';
    case 'Closeout':
      return 'white';
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML: (focus on the ngStyle)

```
<ul class="tabs" id="tabsList" *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="flight-title"> {{ tab.flightName }} </a>
      <a [ngStyle]="{'background': getBackColor(tab.control) }" class="stage"> {{ tab.stagePhase }}
      </a>
      <em (click)="closeTab(tabs.indexOf(tab))" class="close-icon"> </em>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Problem:

Now for the second `<a>` tag, I'd like to have 2 functions called: getBgColor() and getTxtColor(). But simply adding another function doesn't work:

```
<a [ngStyle]="{'background': getBgColor(tab.control)}, {'color': getTxtColor(tab.control) }" class="stage"> {{ tab.stagePhase }}
      </a>
```

With the extra function:

```
getTxtColor(control) {
    switch (control) {
      case 'View Only':
        return 'white';
      case 'Plan and Load':
        return 'white';
      case 'Closeout':
        return 'black';
    }
  }
```

I can't do both of these functions and they need to be returned, what are my options?

Comment: I think you want something like `[ngStyle]="{'background': getBgColor(tab.control), 'color': getTxtColor(tab.control)}"`

Comment: This was what I was originally trying to do yes. I think I had the wrong ```{```  placement.  But I was worried ngStyle wouldn't allow the use of multiple functions.

Comment: Please avoid functions in your bindings. Prefer to use `BehaviorSubject`, `Observable`, `.pipe(map( => ))` and the amazing `| async` pipe instead, to increase the performance

Comment: @pieterjan I know that using a class method in template is not good for the performance, but I'm not sure how to achieve this formatting for both attributes.

Comment: Did you consider using `[style.background]="..." [style.color]="..."`?

Comment: No I did not. That seems like if would be more straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NgStyle *does* allow the use of multiple functions. But they need to be within only one set of brackets.

Try with only one bracket pair `{}`:

```css
[ngStyle]="{'background': getBgColor(tab.control), 'color': getTxtColor(tab.control) }"
```

Comment: Thank you! I had just found this issue with the useful advice from Chris Yungmann

Answer (score 2):

[ngStyle] admit an object, so your function can return an object with properties "color" and "background".

```
getStyle(control)
{
  if (control=="View Only")
     return { "background-color":"#ffcccc00",color:"white"}

  ...
}
```

See that if the property has an `-` we use quotes

BTW, Why not add a property "style" to your tabs?

```
tabs = [
    {
      flightName: "Flight 1",
      stagePhase: "PRE-FPE",
      control: "View Only",
      style:{ "background-color":"#ffcccc00",color:"white"}
    },
    {
      flightName: "Flight 2",
      stagePhase: "PLANNING",
      control: "Plan and Load"
      style:{ color:"white"}
    },
    {
      flightName: "Flight 3",
      stagePhase: "PLANNING",
      control: "Closeout",
      style:{ "background-color":"white",color:"#ffcccc00"}
    },
    {
      flightName: "Flight 4",
      stagePhase: "FPE",
      control: "View Only"
      style:{ "background-color":"#ffcccc00",color:"white"}
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Checking this out now. Thanks for your response!